Flickering WS28xx LEDS when using TWAI in WLED project
I'm trying to receive CAN-bus commands and integrate that with existing WLED source code to light up a WS2812b LED strip.
The project hardware is based on the ESP32-WROOM-32 chip with level shifters, can transceivers etc. To help I'm using the library ESP32-TWAI-CAN @ 1.0.1. In my usermod the code looks like this:
#include "wled.h"
#include <ESP32-TWAI-CAN.hpp>

#define CAN_RX    18
#define CAN_TX    19
#define CAN_READ_TIMEOUT 0


class CanUsermod : public Usermod
{

setup() {

   [...]

   twai_filter_config_t f_config = TWAI_FILTER_CONFIG_ACCEPT_ALL();
   twai_general_config_t g_config = {.mode = TWAI_MODE_LISTEN_ONLY, .tx_io = (gpio_num_t) CAN_TX, .rx_io = (gpio_num_t) CAN_RX,
                                            .clkout_io = TWAI_IO_UNUSED, .bus_off_io = TWAI_IO_UNUSED,
                                            .tx_queue_len = 5, .rx_queue_len = 5,
                                            .alerts_enabled = TWAI_ALERT_NONE,  .clkout_divider = 0,
                                            .intr_flags = ESP_INTR_FLAG_LEVEL1};
   twai_timing_config_t t_config = TWAI_TIMING_CONFIG_250KBITS();
   ESP32Can.begin(ESP32Can.convertSpeed(250),
                    CAN_TX,
                    CAN_RX,
                    5,
                    5,
                    &f_config,
                    &g_config,
                    &t_config);
}

[...]

void loop()
{
   while(ESP32Can.readFrame(rxFrame, CAN_READ_TIMEOUT))
      [...]
   }
}

I Do get the WLED to work and I Do receive correct CAN-messages and can read them in the usermod.
However
When I try to run both at the same time, i.e. Have canbus traffic and light up WS28xx LEDS the leds flicker. The flicker is also happening when I have the Solid effect selected.

If I disconnect the canbus the flickering stops
If I comment out the ESP32Can.begin([...]) the flickering stops

Things that didn't work & I've checked:

Change RX & TX Queue length
Setting can filter to reject all {.acceptance_code = 0, .acceptance_mask = 0x00000000, .single_filter = true}
Setting the .intr_flags=ESP_INTR_FLAG_LEVEL3 in t_config
Setting the CAN_READ_TIMEOUT to 0, 10, 100
Comment out the while-loop in the loop() function
Verifying that there is no ringing on the data output channel from the controller board.
Verifying that the logical voltage levels for the data output channel are correct.
Verifying the voltage supply to the led strip is correct.
Change the LED data output from GPIO 16 to GPIO 4.

This has lead me to believe that the ISR for the TWAI interface is causing jitter in the generation of the 800kHz bit pattern to the leds.
Should I be looking for ways of suspending interrupts during the bit-generation for the leds and if so where and how?

The issue is likely caused by interrupts interfering with the precise timing needed for WS2812b LEDs. You can fix this by temporarily disabling interrupts while updating the LEDs and re-enabling them afterward. Keep the LED update section short to minimize the impact on other processes.
If this doesn’t resolve the issue, consider using hardware timers or DMA to handle the LED updates more efficiently.
